# How to store the title of the page under test

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to use the gotoIf command provided by sideflow.js.
As Selenium seems unable to delete "HttpOnly" session cookies, I need to check the title of the current page to check if I am still on our login page or if I'm already logged in.

In order to make this check, I am using the following gotoIf command:

```
Command: gotoIf
Target: javascript{(document.title!="CAS – Central Authentication Service");}
Value: Portal
```

which does not work.

When I dump the value of the document.title:

```
Command: store
Target:javascript{document.title}
Value: PageTitle

Command: echo
Target: ${PageTitle}
```

I get the title of the test (title of the html file storing the test) instead of the title of the page under test.

Does someone have an idea on how to work this around?

I would like (as much as possible) to avoid using code (c# or ruby) and keep the html/selenium-ide combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the page Title You can  use the commands like

"storeTitle"

"storeAllWindowTitles"

Answer (score 1):

Getting title of page you can used `storetitle` command in selenium ide

```
 storetitle   |      cheeapairticket,flight,hotel...       | title 
 Echo         | ${title}
```

i give you a example of makemytrip site. Check image here, this will provide you clear idea

[image]